# Using FontAwesome in a tabbar with React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, icons

I am new to react native and am trying to create a tabbar using createBottomTabNavigator. I would like each tab to have its own icon.

I have followed the following tutorial which uses FontAwesome to display the tab icon.

[Tutorial](https://whatdidilearn.info/2018/12/02/react-native-tab-navigation.html)

When I run my app in the iso simulator the tabs display but the icons don't.

[image: Tabs]

Here is my code

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import Icon  from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5";
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import SecondActivity from './second';

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen,
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) =>
      <Icon name="home" size={25} color={tintColor} />
      
  }
},
  Events: { screen: SecondActivity,
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) =>
      <Icon name="chart-bar" size={25} color={tintColor} />
  }
}
  }
);

const MyStack = createStackNavigator({ 
  Tabs: {
    screen: TabNavigator
 }, 
  Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen
    },
    Events: {
      screen: SecondActivity
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Tabs',
  }
);
  
export default createAppContainer(MyStack);
```

How do I get the icons to display?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you that is a bit different that what you did in there .. so

```
const config = Platform.select({
  web: { headerMode: "screen" },
  default: {}
})


const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen
  },
  config
)

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-calendar" : "md-calendar"}
    />
  )
}

HomeStack.path = ""
```

and them you can do like this in createBottomTabNavigator

```
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HomeStack,
  }, 
  {
    activeColor: '#000'
  }
```

Comment: this code causes an error, "can't find variable: config"

Comment: sadly i still have no icon, I don't think you fully understood my question

Answer (score 0):

```js
// You can import Ionicons from @expo/vector-icons if you use Expo or
// react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons otherwise.
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let IconComponent = Ionicons;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = focused
            ? 'ios-information-circle'
            : 'ios-information-circle-outline';
          // Sometimes we want to add badges to some icons.
          // You can check the implementation below.
          IconComponent = HomeIconWithBadge;
        } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
          iconName = focused ? 'ios-list-box' : 'ios-list';
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here!
        return <IconComponent name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  }
);
```

***Link : https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/basic-tabs-v3***

***Link : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html***